# Convert cells(1,1) into "A1" and vice versa

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am working on an worksheet generator in Excel 2007. I have a certain layout I have to follow and I often have to format cells based on input. Since the generator is dynamic I have to calculate all kinds of ranges, merge cells, etc.

How can I convert values like this?

`Cells(1,1)` into `A1` and vice versa

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to do this? I'd sure like to see an example in which it is necessary to do something like this.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett  - I'm iterating through my sheet (in macro) having coordinates, but I want to create equations with human-friendly "A1" format.

Comment: @witkacy26 Sounds great

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The [Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property of a cell can get this for you:

```
MsgBox Cells(1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

returns `A1`.

The other way around can be done with the `Row` and `Column` property of `Range`:

```
MsgBox Range("A1").Row & ", " & Range("A1").Column
```

returns `1,1`.

Comment: alternatively `.Address(0,0)`