# Excel How to obtain the char of a column

Tags: excel

How to find the char of number of a column?
`COLUMN` function can only obtain the char of column, but I want to obtain like the `27-column` is `AA`, since in the $INDIRECT$ function, if I want to use the abstract value like `INDIRECT($A$1)` I have to use the char instead of `R1C1` form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert cells(1,1) into "A1" and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262743/convert-cells1-1-into-a1-and-vice-versa), although only if you are using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`ADDRESS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) function, if you are using cell functions rather than VBA programming. On my Excel install:

```
=ADDRESS(1,1)
```

Gives `$A1$1`.

```
=ADDRESS(1,1,1,0)
```

Gives `R1C1`.

```
=ADDRESS(1,1,1,1)
```

Gives `$A1$1`.

I must have different defaults than you, but the fourth parameter will switch between `R1C1` and `A1` styles.

Now, if you just want the column letter, one way is to [delete the row text](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-column-number-to-letter), for instance:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,27,4,1),"1","")
```

This gives `AA`. `ADDRESS(1,27,4,1)` returns `AA1` - note that I set the third parameter to `4` to say to return relative (no `$`) addresses, then [`SUBSTITUTE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) replaces the `1` (the row number we passed in to `ADDRESS`) with the empty string.

Comment: But, I only want row `A`, not the whole address, how to do this?